# The browser is not receiving the JWT cookie after deploying the app on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, fetch

I am working on an application with backend and frontend separately. After I deployed the app on Heroku I can't get the cookie when login using the front-end application (in Postman is working). During the development on localhost it was working.

I used on the backend the 'cors' middleware with the origin set to the deployed host for frontend app and credentials set to true

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://assistcar-client.herokuapp.com',
    credentials: true
}));
app.options('*', cors());
```

Here I'm sending the JWT cookie in the end of login controller

```
cookieOptions = {
        maxAge: process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60,
        httpOnly: true
    }
    
    if (req.secure === true || req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') cookieOptions.secure = true;

    res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        token
    });
```

Also when trying to fetch from the frontend I set the credentials to 'include' (as I saw in the other posts here on StackOverflow), but it's not working, the cookie is not received by the browser after login (and the response is ok)

```
const response = await fetch('https://assistcar-server.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(bodyData)
        });

        return await response.json();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A `httpOnly` cookie can't be read on the client-side. And even if you remove that flag, you still have the problem that your client URL cannot read cookies that are set from the server URL. Why do you need the cookie on the client-side in the first place?

Comment: @str that cookie contains the authentication token (JWT)... when i ran the client on my loacal machine with live-server it was working, now after deploy it is not working anymore

Comment: I have the same issue, has this been solved? If yes, how?